# Error: ConvertTo-SecureString : Key not valid for use in specified state

Tags: powershell

We have one script which has been used to store password to a text file and then the mail script recalls/reuses this password from the password text file to run the master script. 
I am getting below error,after changing the password.

```
Script used to generate secure password:
"Password" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File "D:\Scripts\Password.txt"
```

Error we are getting now:

```
At C:\Scripts\Lync_HealthCheck_Prod.ps1:1199 char:82
+ $PasswrdS = Get-Content C:\Windows\System32\SecStrng.sec | convertto-securest
ring <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ConvertTo-SecureString], C
   ryptographicException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ImportSecureString_InvalidArgument_Cryptographic
   Error,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertToSecureStringCommand

New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "Cannot process ar
gument because the value of argument "password" is null. Change the value of ar
gument "password" to a non-null value."
At C:\Scripts\Lync_HealthCheck_Prod.ps1:1218 char:27
+  $Creds1      = New-Object <<<<  System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -A
rgumentList $CheckUser1, $PasswrdS
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvoca
   tionException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.Power
   Shell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Would be great if you can help.

Comment: what this has to do with `Key not valid for use in specified state` ?

Answer (score 2):

The error message claims that you are handling `null` values:

> "Cannot process argument because the value of argument "password" is null.

So, double-check that you actually are reading good content from the password file. The location in `C:\Windows\System32` very hints that the process is looking for it from wrong location.

```
$PasswrdS = Get-Content C:\Windows\System32\SecStrng.sec
```

Comment: @Christian.K Not according to the error message. It explicitly says that `SecStrng.sec` file is being read from system32 and piped to `ConvertTo-SecureString`.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly same problem, due to NTFS rights mismatch on the sec file. Get-content  is OK, but not call of Convertto-SecureString.
User who created the password file was not the user who executed the program.
I put total control on this file for both users. It is OK now.

To be more accurate : I connected with account needed to run, drop and recreated the secure file containing credentials. This file is useful only for this account